# Why is AMPPS unable to download composer.phar when installing Laravel 5?

Tags: php, macos, laravel-5, osx-yosemite, ampps

Let me start off by saying I'm completely new to Laravel and I would say I'm a beginner at PHP given how long it's been since I last did any PHP development. I'm running Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.2) and I've installed AMPPS 3.0. I have installed composer and Laravel (as per instructions found [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0)) as well. Now when I try to install Laravel on AMPPS (via http://localhost/ampps) I get the following messages:

> The following errors were found :
>
> - Could not download composer.phar
> - Could not install composer

[image: Screenshot of error on AMPPS]

Could someone please enlighten me as to why this is happening? Also is this step necessary since I already have Laravel installed on my mac?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: I have no idea.

Long answer: I found this [link](http://www.ampps.com/wiki/Installing_Laravel_Framework)  when i was having some trouble with this myself.

Basically what's missing was adding the ampps php path in the bash file.

```
export AMPPS_PHP=/Applications/AMPPS/php/bin
export PATH="$AMPPS_PHP:$PATH"
```

Then, moving composer to user/bin directory with

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

I just included the big parts of what was missing in my case. Then install laravel as normal.